# Origen y área de uso de adjetivos grandilocuentes para reforzar ofensas

Tags: uso-de-palabras, diferencias-regionales, adjetivos, lenguaje-peyorativo

Oyendo una obra de 'Les luthiers' llamada [cartas de color](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=plCaS5aKteg), hacia el minuto 10:51, mencionan como todas los miembros del coro "(...) cantan como el reverendo. (...)". A un nivel popular, suele ponerse una grosería o una palabra ofensiva para dar mayor fuerza al insulto, lo que se deja a la imaginación del oyente en el video. De la misma forma se usa por ejemplo el término *soberano* en el caso

> Me importa un soberano comino lo que pienses, tienes que hacerlo

(Pueden cambiar el comino por otra palabra más ofensiva)

El DAMER deja el término [reverendo](http://lema.rae.es/damer/?key=reverendo) como muy grande en Suramérica, México, Cuba y Honduras, mas no se toma el término soberano. ¿Cuál es el área de influencia de soberano como hiperbólico? ¿Desde cuándo se usan estas palabras con el sentido mencionado?

Comment: En Argentina la "esposa" del _reverendo_ es la _recalcada_ ("...y te puedes ir a la racalcada (...) de tu hermana"). Aunque no significa "digno", como reverendo y soberano, "recalcada" igual me suena a "importante".

Comment: @Rodrigo También usamos "reverenda".

Comment: muy interesante con el "me importa" por que la grandilocuencia nos dice que es todo lo contrario... sera simple sarcasmo ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Motivo

Parece que hay dos caminos posibles hasta tales frases peyorativos:

1. un término del "sagrado" > un término que significa grande o poderoso > una plena superlativa
2. un término del "sagrado" > un termino que se asocia con las cualidades negativas de figuras religiosas <sup>(posiblemente por ironía)</sup> > un peyorativo

En cuanto a por que se usa semejantes palabras en lugar de otros, en muchas lenguas hay una tendencia de gravitar a [dos temas](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lenguaje_soez) en el lenguaje soez:

- el sagrado (cosas religiosas, cosas de tu madre, tu país, tu monarca etc)
- el tabú (el sexo, escatología etc)

Puedes ver el primero también en las frases:

- me cago en **Dios**
- **hostia** puta

etc

---

---

## Primeras apariciones

### Soberano

Las primeras instancias de la frase "soberano + insulto" son de los primeros del siglo XIX:

> El populacho de París corrió á las armas por la remoción del virtuoso Ministro , y como **soberano estúpido** pidió á Neker, llevando su busto y el de Felipe de Orleans por la calles.
>
> - [*Conspiración de los sofistas de la impiedad contra la religión y el estado*](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=LY6CY0tbKt0C&pg=PA206&dq="soberano+est%C3%BApido"), Barruel (1814)

> Qué importa que reciba el collar **un soberano imbécil** , que lo use un grande de España de medianas dotes, que lo lleve algun ministro, aborrecido quizás por su mismo talento para lo malo y su carácter rudo, si al par premia los méritos ...
>
> ...
>
> Felipe el Bueno crecia y se educaba en los momentos mismos en que Su padre disputaba en Francia el dominio del reino, gobernado por **un soberano imbécil**.
>
> - [*Inclita militar órden de San Juan de Jerusalen ó de Malta...*](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=8s-BuCRDD7cC&q="soberano+imb%C3%A9cil"), José Gil Dorregaray (1864)

En esta época soberano tenía una significación secundaria:

> **SOBERANO.** Por extenſión, vale tambien altivo, ſoberbio, ò preſumido.
>
> - *1739 ACADEMIA AUTORIDADES (S-Z)*

aunque ya había notado como 'ant.' poco después de estes casos primeros:

> **SOBERANO, NA** adj. ... || ant. Altivo, soberbio ó presumido.
>
> - *1852 ACADEMIA USUAL*

---

### Reverendo

La primera aparición de *reverendo + insulto* bien puede ser literal (o irónico):

> ... como ese *Ministrillo Quinni*, (asi llamo yo a ese **Reverendo imbécil** el Señor *Combermere de Saint Quintin*,) quieran tener el derecho de dictar leyes a gentes honradas que tienen que comer, y que podrian, si fuera necesario, comprarlos á ...
>
> - [*Revista gaditana: 11*](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=EDkPAQAAMAAJ&pg=PA168&dq="reverendo+imb%C3%A9cil") (1840)

Después hay:

> Ay, Simón! rompe el vaso de la existencia pronto, lo más pronto posible, que es un **solemne y reverendo tonto** quien vive en ese mundo aborrecible.
>
> - [*Despues de la muerte: drama en tres actos, original y en verso*](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=_9AOAQAAIAAJ&q="reverendo+tonto"), Manuel José Othón (1886)

Mucho más antes hay el uso de *reverendo* con la definición de "demasiadamente circunspecto":

> Iba camino un Abad,
>   Muy gordo, y **muy reverendo**...
>
> - [*La gran comedia: No puede ser*](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=CUJhAAAAcAAJ&pg=PP19&lpg=PP19&dq="muy+gordo+y+muy+reverendo"), Don Agustin Moreto (1675)

---

### Solemne

Que nos traje a "solemne + ...":

> Y quando eſte arrogante Fariſeo fuera tan juſto, como el ſe precia, era **ſolemne diſparate**, conocerſelo el...
>
> - [*Post Pentecosten*](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=TTey1KON6-IC&pg=PA253&dq="solemne+disparate"), Dionisio Jubero (1610)

> ... adonde irá el pobre Caballero?....
>   Digo que es un **solemne majadero**
>
> - [*Fabulas En Verso Castelano Para El Uso Del Real Seminario Bascongado*](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=5PJFAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA10&dq="solemne+majadero"), Félix Maria Samaniego (1784)

> Y con esto se fue corriendo á sus borricos, que paciendo estaban no muy lexos, alegrandose de verse libre del Tio Gil, á quien dió por **un solemne tonto**...
>
> ... á quien dieron antes por un **solemne tonto**...
>
> - [*El Tio Gil Mamúco*](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=FpzBkxAVFcIC&pg=PA188&dq="solemne+tonto"), D.F.V.Y.C.P. (1789)

Aunque sea el más antiguo que se usa en estes contextos, no se describe así en los diccionarios hasta el siglo XX:

> **SOLEMNE**... || **7.** Encarece en sentido peyorativo la significación de algunos nombres. <sub>SOLEMNE</sub> *disparate*
>
> - *1925 ACADEMIA USUAL*

---

---

**See also:**

- https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/reverendo-gilipollas.1813414/

Comment: Cuando hablas de "apariencias" creo que te refieres a "apariciones". ¿Es así?

Comment: Tengo una duda, ¿eres hispanohablante o cuál es tu lengua materna?

Comment: @Rodrigo ah sí *apariciones, gracias. Mi lengua materna es el inglés - empecé a aprender español hace un par de años. Me uní a este sitio para aprender más sobre el idioma y para compartir las cosas interesantes que he descubierto en mis propios estudios :)

Comment: Pues es fascinante que en apenas un par de años tengas tal dominio del idioma. ¡Enhorabuena! Y qué bien que se haya generado una relación simbiótica con este sitio :)

Comment: Vaya, nunca me di cuenta de que no eres hispanohablante (de cuna). Felicitaciones por tu dominio, es muy bueno.

Answer (score 0):

En España y desde que existe el español como idioma, de hecho hoy en día cuasi-relegadas.

Desde siglo de oro de la literatura española hasta mediados del siglo pasado su uso era muy habitual, principalmente en estilo irónico o con doble sentido, tanto en el leguaje hablado como en la literatura.

De hecho la gente “culta” no hablaba tan mal como lo hace ahora, era impensable que un licenciado o señor usase insultos (palabras mal sonantes) en público.

Comment: Hola, y bienvenido al sitio. Agradecemos tu respuesta, pero sería conveniente que la dotaras de fuentes que acreditaran su validez. ¿Podrías añadirlas?